# Prove: $3(a^4+b^4+c^4)+48\ge 8(a^2b+b^2c+c^2a)$

Tags: inequality

Let $a, b, c$ - real numbers. Prove that $3(a^4+b^4+c^4)+48\ge8(a^2b+b^2c+c^2a)$

Comment: I think is $3(a^4+b^4+c^4)+48\ge 8(a^3b+b^3c+c^3a)$?

Comment: I dont thinks so...

Comment: this problem from some book? or tell us background?

Comment: I kown famous valise(2004) inequality: $$(a^2+b^2+c^2)^2\ge 3(a^3b+b^3c+c^3a)$$ and if and only if $a=b=c$ and $a:b:c=\sin^2{\dfrac{\pi}{7}}:\sin^2{\dfrac{2\pi}{7}}:\sin^2{\dfrac{3\pi}{7}}$

Comment: It is thought to be frm book, but it iss not for sure...

Comment: and from Vasile book,have this $3(a^4+b^4+c^4)+4(a^3b+b^3c+c^3a)\ge0$ for all real numbers $a,b,c$.maybe your inequality is wrong.

Comment: Hello, welcome to Math.SE. Please read http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/9960#9960 and the others there for information on writing a good question for this site. In particular, people will be more willing to help if you edit your question to include some motivation, and an explanation of your own attempts.

Comment: The conditions of task are right, we need to prove that inequality:         3(a4+b4+c4)+48≥8(a2b+b2c+c2a)

Comment: All that is an old-fashioned math. The Mathematica command $$ Minimize[3*(a^4 + b^4 + c^4) + 48 - 8*(a^2*b + a*c^2 + b^2*c), \{a, b,   c\}]$$ outputs $$\{0, \{a -> 2, b -> 2, c -> 2\}\} .$$

Comment: @user64494 Mathematica isn't mathematics!

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Consider the following inequality obtained by AM-GM inequality:
$$
2a^4+b^4+16=a^4+a^4+b^4+16\geq 4\sqrt[4]{16a^8b^4}=8ba^2
$$
Writing down similar inequalities for other pairs we get:
$$
2b^4+c^4+16\geq 8cb^2\\
2c^4+a^4+16\geq 8ac^2
$$
It is enough to sum up all these inequalities and we get the desired inequality.

Comment: It's nice!..   +1